# How to import Yii Controller in Yii widgets

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

How to import Yii Controller in Yii widgets;

My Widget code is:

```
class RecentBlogsWidget extends CWidget { 


public $showblogs;


public function run() {

    Yii::import("application.components.Controller");

    $model = Blog::model()->activeBlogsWidget($this->showblogs)->findAll();

    $this->render('RecentBlogs',
                     array(
                            'model' => $model,
                            )
                );
}
```

}

Now I call my component/controller function `$this->getAuthor($blog->author_id)` in this widget view but giving me error:

`RecentBlogsWidget and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getAuthor".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just imported my Controller in my

```
  views/RecentBlogsWidget.php     
  Yii::import('application.components.Controller');
```

and then call my method like this:

```
  Controller::getAuthor($blog->author_id);
```

it is working now for me.